# Database and large Timeseries - Downsampling - OpenTSDB InfluxDB Google DataFlow

Tags: database, time-series, google-cloud-dataflow, influxdb, opentsdb

I have a project where we sample "large" amount of data on per-second basis. Some operation are performed as filtering and so on and it needs then to be accessed as second, minute, hour or day interval.

We currently do this process with an SQL based system and a software that update different tables (daily average, hourly averages, etc...).

We are currently looking if other solution could fit our needs and I went across several solutions, as **open tsdb, google cloud dataflow and influxdb**.

All seem to address timeseries needs, but it gets difficult to get information about the internals. opentsdb do offer downsampling but it is not clearly specified how.

The need is since we can query vast amount of data, for instance a year, if the DB downsample at the query and is not pre-computed, it may take a very long time.

As well, downsampling needs to be "updated" when ever "delayed" datapoint are added.

On top of that, upon data arrival we perform some processing (outliner filter, calibration) and those operation should not be written on the disk, several solution can be used like a Ram based DB but perhaps some more elegant solution that would work together with the previous specification exists.

I believe this application is not something "extravagant" and that it must exist some tools to perform this, I'm thinking of stock tickers, monitoring and so forth.

Perhaps you may have some good suggestions into which technologies / DB I should look on.

Thanks.

Comment: For time series databases period aggregations (aka downsampling, averaging, summarization, etc) is one of standard use cases. They are all pretty good at it, at least the basics - avg, min, max, percentiles, first/last, etc. opentsdb for instance reads raw data and returns aggregates and then queues these aggregates for re-use. This is how it works last time I checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish such use cases pretty easily with Google Cloud Dataflow. Data preprocessing and optimizing queries is one of major scenarios for Cloud Dataflow.

We don't provide a "downsample" primitive built-in, but you can write such data transformation easily. If you are simply looking at dropping unnecessary data, you can just use a [`ParDo`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do). For really simple cases, [`Filter.byPredicate`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Filter#byPredicate-PredicateT-) primitive can be even simpler.

Alternatively, if you are looking at merging many data points into one, a common pattern is to [window](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing) your `PCollection` to subdivide it according to the timestamps. Then, you can use a [`Combine`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/combine) to merge elements per window.

Additional processing that you mention can easily be tacked along to the same data processing pipeline.

In terms of comparison, Cloud Dataflow is not really comparable to databases. Databases are primarily storage solutions with processing capabilities. Cloud Dataflow is primarily a data processing solution, which connects to other products for its storage needs. You should expect your Cloud Dataflow-based solution to be much more scalable and flexible, but that also comes with higher overall cost.

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow is for inline processing as the data comes in. If you are only interested in summary and calculations, dataflow is your best bet.

If you want to later take that data and access it via time (time-series) for things such as graphs, then InfluxDB is a good solution though it has a limitation on how much data it can contain.

If you're ok with 2-25 second delay on large data sets, then you can just use BigQuery along with Dataflow. Dataflow will receive, summarize, and process your numbers. Then you submit the result into BigQuery. HINT, divide your tables by DAYS to reduce costs and make re-calculations much easier.

We process 187 GB of data each night. That equals 478,439,634 individual data points (each with about 15 metrics and an average of 43,000 rows per device) for about 11,512 devices.

Secrets to BigQuery:
LIMIT your column selection. Don't ever do a select * if you can help it.

;)